# Binary unions are effective in abelian categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $\mathsf{A}$ be an abelian category and $S,T\hookrightarrow M$ be two subobjects. We can naturally form the commutative square

[image]

and it's surely cartesian. (Since intersections are given by pullbacks.) In the second volume of the *Handbook of Categorial Algebra* (proposition 1.7.4), F. Borceux proves that this square is also cocartesian. (This is the definition of "binary unions are effective".) A little later, he proves that

> In an abelian category, the pushout of a monomorphism is still a monomorphism and the pushout square is also a pullback. Dually, in an abelian category the pullback of an epimorphism is still an epimorphism and the corresponding pullback square is also a pushout.

and affirms that this generalizes the effectiveness of binary unions. **Why?**

I tried to prove this in the following way: consider the pushout of $S\leftarrow S\cap T\to T$, whose arrows are monic due to the aforementioned theorem.

[image]

The universal property of pushouts then gives a morphism $Q\to S\cup T$. If this morphism is monic, then $Q$ is a subobject of $M$ that is bigger than $S$ and $T$, while being smaller than $S\cup T$. But, by its very definition, $S\cup T$ is the smallest such object; proving that $Q\cong S\cup T$ and finishing the argument. **But I don't know if $Q\to S\cup T$ is indeed monic.**

Comment: By $S \cup T$ you presumably mean the supremum in the poset of subobjects of $M$?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Precisely! And $S\cap T$ is the infimum.

Comment: I am probably confused about terminology, but isn't "cocartesian square" the same thing as "pushout", in which case you are asking why two pushouts of the same diagram are isomorphic?

Comment: Let $D$ be the first square that appears in my post. I know that it's a pullback and I want to prove that it's also a pushout. (And I want to use the result cited in gray to do it.) In my attempt I construct a diagram which is, by definition, a pushout and, by the result cited, also a pullback. But I don't know if it coincides with $D$. (I.e., if $Q$ is isomorphic to $S\cup T$.)

Comment: I think you may be reading too much into "generalise" here. The properties are related conceptually but I do not think one implies the other.

Comment: That's sad @ZhenLin. My "proof" seems to get so close...

Comment: Close only counts in horseshoes, hand grenades and approximation theory; no luck in categories.